# more ruby way of gsub from array

Tags: ruby

My goal is to let there be `x` so that `x("? world. what ? you say...", ['hello', 'do'])` returns `"hello world. what do you say..."`.

I have something that works, but seems far from the "Ruby way":

```
def x(str, arr, rep='?')
  i = 0
  query.gsub(rep) { i+=1; arr[i-1] }
end
```

Is there a more idiomatic way of doing this? (Let me note that speed is the most important factor, of course.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are talking about the ruby way to accomplish the goal of the function, I would just use `"%s world" % ['hello']`.

If you are just asking about the implementation, it looks fine to me. If you don't mind destroying the array, you could tighten it up a bit by doing

```
query.gsub(rep) { arr.shift }
```

Comment: Cloning the array first would solve the problem of destroying the array if that's an issue.

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible in your use-case I would not add the replacement character as a paramater and then use the standard ruby string formatting mechanism to format the string. This gives you much better control of the variables that you want replaced within the string.

```
def x(string, values, rep='%s')
  if rep != '%s'
    string.gsub!(rep, '%s')
  end
  string % values
end

a = %w[hello do 12]

puts x("? world what ? you say ?", a, '?')
puts x("%s world what %s you say %3.2f", a)
puts x("%s world what %s you say %3.2f", a, '%s')
```

And the output from this is as follows

```
hello world what do you say 12
hello world what do you say 12.00
hello world what do you say 12.00
```

You will need to be careful with this as too few arguments will cause exceptions so you may wish to trap exceptions and behave appropriately. Without knowing your use-case it's hard to tell if this is appropriate or not.

Comment: Thanks very much--mckeed's happened to fit my case better, but your solution is something I'm glad to know about for the future.

Answer (score 2):

Shorter version:

```
def x(str, *vals) str.gsub('?', '%s') % vals end

puts x("? world what ? you say ?", 'hello', 'do', '12')
puts x("%s world what %s you say %3.2f", 'hello', 'do', '12')
puts x("%s world what %s you say %3.2f", 'hello', 'do', '12')
```

Output:

```
hello world what do you say 12
hello world what do you say 12.00
hello world what do you say 12.00
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the most idiomatic and readable way is this:

```
def x(str, arr, rep='?')
  arr.inject(str) {|memo, i| memo.sub(rep, i)}
end
```

It probably won't have the best possible performance (or it might be very fast — Ruby's speed depends **a lot** on the specific implementation you're using), but it's very simple. Whether it's appropriate depends on your goal at the moment.